Eclipse console 'Standard In text color' option is couldn't applied
enter image description here
Hello everyone,
I set the 'In text color' option in Eclipse Console, but it appears black, making it very difficult to read when using Dark mode.
can I solve this?
My Eclipse version is 4.16.0.
The version cannot be updated because it is being used by a company.
Thank you for your kindness.
I tried changing all the colors in settings but they didn't take effect.

Solved: Change 'Hyperlink text color' in Colors and Fonts settings.
